In MS Excel track progress when items only have expected completion and actual completion dates
I have task items with expected deployment and actual deployment date  and I want to plot these as two line charts showing when project was behind or ahead of schedule. Here is the data..



Expected Deployment Date
Actual Deployment Date




20-Sep
20-Sep


20-Sep
20-Sep


27-Sep
27-Sep


27-Sep
29-Sep


4-Oct
5-Oct


4-Oct
7-Oct


11-Oct
13-Oct


18-Oct
19-Oct


18-Oct
18-Oct


25-Oct
25-Oct


25-Oct
25-Oct


25-Oct
25-Oct


8-Nov
8-Nov


8-Nov
8-Nov


15-Nov
15-Nov


15-Nov
16-Nov


15-Nov
17-Nov





So what is the actual problem?

@Michal The data on the chart is wrong. Chart is posted here just to explain what kind of output I want to have. Any ideas ?

It's really SuperUser question as it has nothing to do with programming and such.  Assuming you want to show the time difference between the two dates, you simply have to calculate it and display it as such.

